# Weird Timezone Issues with Symfony2/Twig

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, timezone, twig

I am trying to figure out a weird issue with timezones when displaying a datetime with Twig in a Symfony2 application, and have a couple of questions about what I am seeing on one of my Twig templates when trying to display datetimes.

First, everything I've checked for mis-configuration:

- My entity classes have private properties defined as datetimes, and public getter methods that just return the private propery.
- MySQL has the dates stored in my Timezone (America/New_York);
- My php.ini file has my default timezone set to America/New_York.
- Nowhere am I calling twig's `setTimezone()` method.
- `date_default_timezone_get()` returns 'America/New_York', both from the web and CLI.

### Now for the weirdness

In MySQL my entity's reviewedAt data is `2015-07-08 11:16:00`.

In one of my Twig templates I call:

- `{{ entity.reviewedAt|date('m/d/Y h:i a') }}` I get **07/08/2015 @ 05:16 pm**.
- `{{ entity.reviewedAt|date('m/d/Y h:i a', false) }}` I get **07/08/2015 @ 11:16 am**.

The `false` argument tells Twig to [use the timezone of the datetime object passed to the date filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html#timezone).

When I debug with `{{ dump(entity.reviewedAt) }}` I get:

```
object(DateTime)[879]
  public 'date' => string '2015-07-08 11:16:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/New_York' (length=16)
```

`var_dump($entity-getReviewedAt())` from the controller returns the exact same output as `{{ dump(entity.reviewedAt) }}`;

And this is only happening on one template. Other templates on my site are displaying this same field, using the `date()` filter, without a problem.

#### First question:

Why, when the datetime object already has same timezone as the default set in php.ini do I have to pass the `false` argument?

### Even weirder:

My entity is a child of an `instance`, which has a `releaseDate`. In MySQL, this releaseDate is stored as `2015-07-02 00:00:00`.

When I display the release date in the *same* template with `{{ entity.instance.releaseDate|date('m/d/Y h:i a') }}`, I get **07/02/2015 @ 12:00 am**.

So this property is displaying correctly without passing `false` as the second argument. But when I do a `{{ dump(entity.instance.releaseDate) }}` I get:

```
object(DateTime)[5518]
  public 'date' => string '2015-07-02 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Copenhagen' (length=17)
```

I'm sure Copenhagen is a wonderful city, but why the heck is my datetime set to that?

And if I call `var_dump($entity->getInstance()->getReleaseDate())` from my controller, I get:

```
object(DateTime)[1592]
  public 'date' => string '2015-07-02 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/New_York' (length=16)
```

And *only* when I call `var_dump()` from the controller `{{ entity.instance.releaseDate|date('m/d/Y h:i a') }}` displays **07/02/2015 @ 06:00 am** and `{{ dump(entity.instance.releaseDate) }}` displays:

```
object(DateTime)[1592]
  public 'date' => string '2015-07-02 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/New_York' (length=16)
```

#### Second question:

What. The. Heck? Why is Twig showing the timezone as Europe/Copenhagen, and why does that go back to America/New_York when I call `var_dump()` from the controller?

Could this have something to do with the proxy classes Doctrine2 loads? When I `{{ dump(entity.instance) }}` I do see that instance is a Doctrine proxy object.

Comment: Does this problem happen when you're using symfony forms? If so you might want to checkout the [DateTimeType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html)